# Riemann integral of the value set

Tags: real-analysis

Assume f is non-negative and integrable over $\mathbb{R}^d$. For each $\alpha>0$, define

$E_{\alpha}=\{x:f(x)>\alpha\}$

Then how we show

$\int_0^{\infty}m(E_{\alpha})d\alpha$ is Riemann integrable and equal to $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx$? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: What is $m(E_\alpha)$?

Comment: Presumably the Lebesgue measure of $E_\alpha$?

Comment: ok, that makes sense. So second question: What does the integral from 0 to $\infty$ mean if $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: Yeah. $m(E_{\alpha})$ denote the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: $m(E_{\alpha})$ is a function of $\alpha$ and it is defined in $(0,\infty)$

Comment: I mean your second integral. You write $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$. What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I see your question. I have edited it.

Comment: Ok, so $\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x)dx$ is a Lebesugue integral?

Comment: I think it means Riemann integral. I am not sure.